# Alignment of matrices in tables (Lyx)

Tags: tables, formatting

[image]

Is there a way to add extra space beyond and above the matrices in the second table? I don't want the table field borders to collapse with the borders of the matrices. It looks weird. I tried to use `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight` but I couldn't manage to do it. They just stretched the matrices too. I also tried to use double space lining. Thank you.

**EDIT**

MWE:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
#Alignment of matrices in tables.lyx
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\lang english
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="3" columns="6">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\series bold
\lang english
Method
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\boldsymbol{G}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\boldsymbol{h}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\boldsymbol{K}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\series bold
\lang english
Name
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\series bold
\lang english
Reference
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
18
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{A}^{T}\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^{T}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{A}^{T}\boldsymbol{b}\\
\boldsymbol{Ac}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\\
\boldsymbol{A}^{-T} & \boldsymbol{0}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
bcr3
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
ref
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
19
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{I} & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{I}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{b}\\
\boldsymbol{A}^{-T}\boldsymbol{c}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
\begin_inset Formula $\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{A}^{T}\\
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{0}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
LSQR
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
ref
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you add a MWE for testing?

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob, sure. I should have done that.

Comment: I played with your .lyx file and can reproduce that `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight` also stretch the matrices. I'm not sure what a solution is.

Comment: @scottkosty neither do I.. Thanks for trying.